# Комбинация постраничной навигации с поиском

Tags: jquery

На странице выводится динамический список с функцией поиска, то есть список обновляется часто, появляются и удаляются новые строки в зависимости от того, что вводят в поиск

```
<table id="users-table">
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    ......
    <tr><td>50</td></tr>
</table>
<div id="pagination" class="pagination"></div>
```

Как привязать функцию обработки к вновь появляющимся элементам, которые не инициированы обработкой, что я делаю не так?

```
$(#users-table tbody).on('change', 'tr', function($) {
            var items = $("#users-table tbody tr");

            var numItems = items.length;
            var perPage = 10;
            items.slice(perPage).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Событие `change` работает только для элементов формы, при изменении атрибута `value`.

Вообще не существует события изменения элемента, поэтому вам нужно найти другое решение, например найти в коде место вставки элементов на страницу и там вызывать ваш обработчик.

Comment: Спасибо большое, буду думать.